# j2me Application shows out of memory exception in JBLEND

Tags: java-me

my j2me application shows out of memory exception in JBLEND. It work fine in JBED. By monitoring the memory, I realized that the document.parse(xmlParser) method consumes a lot of memory. I think the reason for the excption is memory is not freeing after parsing xml. is it right??? How can i solve the problem???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whatever `document.parse(xmlParser)` returns, you should dereference it as soon a you don't need it anymore, i.e. you should set fields pointing to the returned object to `null` (or unset indirect references).

I've never used *JBLEND* or *JBED*, but the [Wireless Toolkit respectively JaveME SDK](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javame/overview/index.html) also has a nice memory profiler which helps you track down memory and object reference problems.

Comment: I have derefernced the document as document = null; after calling the method document.parse(xmlParser). But the result is same.. What can i do for freeing memory??

Comment: @asifkt: It's not good practice and actually this should happen automatically when memory is low, but you could force a run of the garbage collector after the you've set `document = null` by calling `System.gc()`. In this  regard, read also [this post here on SO](http://stackoverflow.com/q/899241/151299) and [these general hints on memory management in JavaME applications](http://j2medevcorner.wordpress.com/2007/02/19/memory-management-in-j2me/).

Comment: @Oben: I called the GC after methods which consumes more memory. But the exception occuring frequency is increased.

Comment: @asifkt: I would analyze the memory consumption more detailed using a memory profiler (see WTK link in answer). There you'll see how much memory your document object consumes exactly and if there are some obstinate references preventing it from being freed by the GC. Finally, if everything works fine in JBED and WTK, the problem may also be caused by a buggy *JBLEND* version.

Comment: I tried with wireless tool kit. I works fine for a heap size of 6mb. As i told, I am runninig this application using JBLEND. I think heap size for this application in JBLEND is less than 6mb. How can I set it to 6MB???

Comment: @asifkt: Sorry, no idea - I never worked with JBLEND. A generic, VM-independent solution would be to find a way to parse the document while consuming less memory.